# PHP foreach loop breaking with sub object

Tags: php, object, foreach

I'm trying to access third party api which gives me object and sub object, for example:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [truncated] => 
    [text] => "some text"
    [user] => stdClass Object
        (
            [count] => 9370
            [comments_enabled] => yes
```

When I try and loop through the object with the following code I get an error at the start of sub-object 'user'. Can anyone help me either 1) iterate through the sub-object, or 2) block the sub-object from the loop.

The code:

```
$test = $s[0];
$obj = new ArrayObject($test);
foreach ($obj as $data => $name) {
print $data . ' - ' . $name . '<br />';
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the 'user' field is an object, so you need to separately run through each field within that object

```
function iterateObject($obj, $name='') {

  //for each element        
  foreach ($obj as $key=>$val) {
    $myName = ($name !='') ? "$name.$key" : $key;

    //if type of the element is an object or array 
    if ( is_object($val) || is_array($val) ) {
      //if so, iterate through its properties
      iterateObject($val, $myName);
    }
    //otherwise output name/ value combination
    else {
      print "$myName - $val <br/>";
    }

  }

}

$test = $s[0];
$obj = new ArrayObject( $test );
iterateObject( $obj );
```

Will output

```
truncated - 
text - some text
user.count - 9370
user.comments_enabled - yes
```

Comment: thanks for that - in addition used the function across three tiers i.e. object - sub object -sub sub object and works (and follows naming conventions as above).

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

function traceObject($object) {
  foreach ($object as $data => $name) {
    if (is_object($name)) {
      traceObject($name);
    } else {
      echo $data . ' - ' . $name .'<br />';
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will iterate through a tree of objects and print key - value pairs...

```
printObject($test);

function printObject($obj) {
    foreach (get_object_vars($obj) as $field => $value) {
        if (is_object($value)) {
            printObject($value);
        } else {
            print $field . ' - ' . $value . '<br />';
        }
    }
}
```